# How does postfix send mail without smtp settings?

Tags: postfix, smtp

I am running vagrant. In it, I have  Ubuntu 14.04 server and installed postfix.
I am able to send email using `sendmail someone@gmail.com` (after typing in body etc.)
This works.

How is postfix able to send email to gmail even though I configured nothing about postfix (did not specify any smtp settings for my gmail accoun, for example)

Also, postfix looks like a full-fledged email server? What can I install so that I can send email without having to install postfix (and without giving any smtp settings for this program X)?

Answer (score 2):

The primary duty of any mail server is to route mails to their destination. When you send an email to `someone@example.org`, using `sendmail someone@example.org` the following happens.

- Your mail is handed over to `SMTP` server on your local machine.
- If you had configured your mail server to route mails (for eg. Send mails of `example.org` to `example.net` server) then your email server will honour it.
- If you had never configured your email server, it will do an `MX` lookup for the domain `example.org` and deliver the mail to the `MX` server of the domain. If `MX` record doesn't exist for that domain, it will try to deliver the mail to `A` record, if available.

You will need an `SMTP` server (`postfix`,`sendmail`,`qmail` or `exim`) to send emails without configuring any SMTP settings. Hope that helps.